# Word 2003/2007 - Multiline Regular Expression

Tags: regex, ms-word, multiline

I have a Word document containing Questions and Answers in the following format:

```
1. What is the name of our planet?
a) Earth
b) Mars
c) Venus
d) Jupiter

ANSWER:
a
TYPE: MC  DIFFICULTY: Easy
KEYWORDS: planet solar system
```

What I need to do is "split" the document in two parts, the first containing only the questions, the second containing only the answers. The result should be as follows.

**Document 1 - Questions**

```
1. What is the name of our planet?
a) Earth
b) Mars
c) Venus
d) Jupiter
```

**Document 2 - Answers**

```
1. ANSWER:
a
TYPE: MC  DIFFICULTY: Easy
KEYWORDS: planet solar system
```

The documents have quite a relatively regular structure, i.e.
- List number
- Question text
- A line containing "ANSWERL:"
- Answer text
- Two CRLF

I tried using Regular Expressions to match the text and extract it from the document, but I have difficulties using Word's proprietary RegEx syntax and I couldn't find out how to make a RegEx that spans multiple lines and multiple document blocks.
I also tried PowerGREP; the RegEx works, but it can only read the plain text from the document and it loses all the lists (e.g. the numbers of both questions and answers) and all the objects (some questions and answers have graphs and tables that I must keep).

To summarize, I have to follow this logic.

1. Select everything (text and objects) from the question
   number until the word "ANSWER" (excluded). Do this for each question
   (i.e. process one question/block at a time).
2. Select everything (text and objects) from the word "ANSWER" until the next question (excluded).

The document is in .DOC format, but I can also save it in .DOCX. Note: I tried parsing the XML of the .DOCX, but it contains thousands of superfluous tags, making everything impossibly complicated.

Comment: The dumb way to do it would be to just paste the file as plain text in an editor, regex sub out the answers in the first one and sub out the questions in the second one, then paste back into word. You could write a script to do that for you if have a bunch of files.

Comment: @inTide: The issue is that some of the questions and answers contain objects (images, graphs, tables) that would get lost in the process. I'd like to avoid manual adjustments, if possible, way too many files involved.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you shouldn't use REGEXP (even if it would be nicer, i'm afraid - and your first tries prove it - that it would be quite hard).

What you can try is to loop through the document with the vba word `find` function with the expression `ANSWER:`.
Then you can loop over each block:

- Cut-paste selection from the beginning till the beginning of
  `ANSWER:` in the *Question document*.
- Cut-paste the next part    (extend selection to the next 3 or 4
  lines) in the *Answer document*.

See [here](http://www.thezcorp.com/VBACodeSamples.aspx) >> chapter *Find, Replace Hard Returns With Manual Line Breaks* for some tips. And this [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm) for more information.